# Titanium SQLite: Database pseudo array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sqlite, matrix, titanium

I have a working app that needs to store up to 4 matrixes of integer data per record. I'm not sure how to get there with Titanium and SQlite.

A record will contain at least 1 but up to 4 matrixes of integers:

The matrix size is variable, each matrix consists of:

1 - 20 rows with 3 columns per row

OR

1 - 20 rows with 6 columns per row

The matrix structure will be identical for each record, i.e. 3 3x20 matrixes in
a record or 4 6x10 matrixes in a record. At this point my app starts, allows the user to choose the matrix parameters then accepts the data entry to fill in the matrix values. The matrixes are actually an JS array of arrays. How can I store an array of arrays and read it back in when I need to?

Edit:  Let me see if I can clarify...

The app I'm working on is a scorecard for archery tournaments, similar in concept to a scorecard in golf. In archery you shoot for a set number of ends with a set number of arrows shot per end. The app asks for the number of ends (up to 20) and the number of arrows shot per end (3 or 6). After each shot the archer enters the score (an integer value).  so for argument's sake say we're scoring for three ends with three arrows per end. We might see something like this:

```
arrow scores
8  8  9    (end 1)
7  9  10   (end 2)
9  9  10   (end 3)
```

There's my matrix that I need to save for this individual record. However, the next tournament I need to score may have a different number of ends and arrows:

```
arrow scores
7 8 9 10 10 10  (end 1)
10 9 9 7 8  10  (end 2)
9  6 6 6  9 9   (end 3) 
7 8 6  7  8 8   (end 4)
10 10 9 8 8 8   (end 5)
```

Let's simplify and say that I want to store the scorecard for one archer per record. I already have my data entry and score tabulation working. I just don't understand the best way to store matrices as illustrated above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend against storing an array of arrays.  Generally speaking, its not terribly efficient to write abstractions with code that are meaningful for reasoning about matrices when make array of arrays a firm concept.  The only exception I've seen is matlab/octave.

I've always found I end up with simpler code when I flatten the data.  With a flat array you'll have to manage the indexing yourself.  A few helper functions make that simple to reason about.

I'm not given much info to go on, but I'd assume that putting the data into two different tables will make things simpler.

```
CREATE TABLE mat3x20 (i1j1, i1j2, i1j2 ....
CREATE TABLE mat6x10 (i1j1, i1j2, i1j2 ....
```

Otherwise you have some weird behavior flag in the data which will make it less obvious what the code is supposed to be doing somewhere in the call stack.